# Return JSON response to image upload in RUBY

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie to `ruby`.The question might sound worthless to some of you. Sorry for that. I'm struggling to find the solution for my problem for the past six hours.

**Aim:**

I have an HTML editor. Here, I want to insert the image into editor which have been uploaded via file dialog.

**What i did**

Once, User uploads the image via file dialog, I will return the path for the image( which one have been constructed dynamically at server side) . I'm using `jquery` `ajaxupload` method for uploading image.

**Where did i struggle**

I have no problem with saving the uploaded image using `Ruby`.

```
class ImageController < ApplicationController
  def upload
    post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    #How to send  back JSON response from here
  end
end
```

I need to send back the uploaded image url to browser as a `JSON` response just like as follows

```
{ 'url' : 'app/uploadedimage/***.**'}
```

In JS, I will use the `url` as `src` for the `image` element just like as follows

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'image/upload',
        *
        *
        *
        success: function (returndata) {
                 var image = document.createElement('img');
                 J(image).attr('src',returndata.url).appendTo(editor);
        },
        error: function(){
                 alert("error in ajax form submission");
            }
```

Thanks in advance for your answers & suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the JSON return in your controller action.

```
def controller_action
  # using sample model and methods
  obj = ModelClass.create_new_object(params)
  url = obj.get_image_url
  render json: {url: url}
end
```

Comment: If it works, mark it as the answer and vote this up. :)

Comment: The `return` keyword is never required since this is implicitly done.

Comment: @SyedHumzaShah : Sure, I will.